# Avoid null reference using c# possibilities

Tags: c#, delegates, code-cleanup

I'm trying to clean up a big handler method that show or not a the label on view.

The actual structure is something like:

```
if (Moo.Foo != null) {
    Show(TrType, LabelType, Moo.Foo.DangerousNullRef + " - " + Moo.Foo.AnotherPossibleNullRef);
}
else {
    DontShowField(TrType);
}
```

I'm thinking in something like send all components involved to a method that do all boring stuff, but:

```
ShowHandlingNull(Moo.Foo != null, TrType, LabelType, Moo.Foo.DangerousNullRef + " - " + Moo.Foo.AnotherPossibleNullRef);
```

Will cause null reference if Moo.Foo is null. Can I delegate or put in some action the behavior and put just one line in my big method?

Comment: What is the desired behavior if `Moo.Foo` is actually null?

Comment: @vcsjones The behavior is call else statement: `DontShowField(TrType)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already the idea of using Func to handle this which seems to me like the best solution, I just made some assumptions on your intention and assume you are trying to get that label text so I wrote it up as such.

```
   private void YourFunction
    {
        Type TrType = this.GetType();
        MooClass Moo = new MooClass();
        LabelTypeEnum LabelType = LabelTypeEnum.something;
        ShowIf(Moo, TrType, LabelType, new Object[] { Moo.Foo, Moo.Foo2, Moo.Foo3 }, a => a.Foo.DangerousNullRef + " - " + a.Foo.AnotherPossibleNullRef);

    }


    void ShowIf(MooClass Moo, Type t, LabelTypeEnum LabelType, IEnumerable<object> PreCheckNullsValues, Func<MooClass, string> mc )
    {
        if (PreCheckNullsValues.Any(a => a == null))
            Show(t, LabelType, mc(Moo));
        else
            DontShowField(t);
    }
```

Here's an assumed skeleton to your supporting code:

```
   enum LabelTypeEnum
    {
        something
    }

    class MooClass
    {
        public FooClass Foo { get; set; }
    }

    class FooClass
    {
        public object DangerousNullRef { get; set; }
        public object AnotherPossibleNullRef { get; set; }
    }

    private void Show(Type TrType, LabelTypeEnum LabelType, string p) { }

    private void DontShowField(Type TrType) { }
```

You could then use the Action to access your properties safely.

Comment: This is a good solution! But I've Foo2, Foo3... Foo15 properties. How can I dynamically do the if clause `if (Moo."FooN" != null)`

Comment: @Custódio Are you trying to check if ANY of the properties on the class are null, or some random subset of the properties are null?

Comment: deepee1 The better answer is Random. I've a big Moo class, I'm refactoring him too, but now I've a lot of properties that I need to verify if is null.

Comment: @Custódio ok, slight variation that allows a set of objects to check for null as well, although the call is getting a bit less elegant now.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider this an improvement, but it can be done using delayed execution through lambda's.

```
ShowHandlingNull(Moo.Foo, TrType, LabelType, f => f.DangerousNullRef, f => f.AnotherPossibleNullRef);

void ShowHandlingNull(Foo foo, object trType, objectLablelType, Func<Foo, object> dangerousNullRefGetter, Funct<Foo, object> anotherDangerousGetter)
{
    if (foo == null) {
        DontShowField(trType);
        return;
    }
    Show(TrType, LabelType, dangerousNullRefGetter(foo) + " - " + anotherDangerousGetter(foo));
}
```

But I think your original `if` null check is easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: This will break if Moo is null

Comment: @sternr so would the op's post of how he's currently doing it

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) guidelines.

For example, Moo.Foo could become an interface, and the actual class should become an implementation of said interface. You create then a MooFooNull class which handles the case where Foo is null, that is the DontShowField method.

```
// On Moo.Foo initialization, if the condition for creating of RealMooFoo are not met.
Moo.Foo = new MooFooNull(this);

// later on ...
Moo.Foo.Show(TrType, LabelType, Moo.Foo.DangerousNullRef + " - " + Moo.Foo.AnotherPossibleNullRef);
```

where MooFooNull's Show method is:

```
void Show(TheClass theClass, object trType, ... ) {
    theClass.DontShowField(trType);
}
```

Comment: this is a solution, but in my method Moo contains a lot of Foo properties. So I'll need to create n * properties extensions. :/ I quickly counted here, its n is around 15

Comment: You could create a DTO with the needed data... ok, keep the if ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you could write yourself some method that acts like Strings "+" and checks for null-References (and add it as an extension-method to string) but I think this would be overkill.
Just change/overload your show-method with a "Moo" (whatever the type might be) parameter and check in there.

Answer (score 0):

why not try and use an extension method which accepts null

```
public static string ShowHandlingNull(this Foo foo, TrType trType, LabelType labelType)
{
    if (foo == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return ......
}

var result = Moo.Foo.ShowHandlingNull(trType, labelType);
```

Comment: this is a solution, but in my method Moo contains a lot of Foo properties. So I'll need to create n * properties extensions. :/
I quickly counted here, its n is around 15

Answer (score 0):

Use a small extension method:

```
public static class OrEmpty<T>(this T instance) where T : class, new()
{
    return instance ?? new T();
}
```

Example:

```
Show(TrType, LabelType, Moo.Foo.OrEmpty().DangerousNullRef + " - " + Moo.Foo.OrEmpty().AnotherPossibleNullRef);
```

Note that it will create a new object per call. You can make it slightly more advanced to avoid creating a lot of objects.